# Php JSON encoding gives result {"table":null}

Tags: php, sql, json, encoding

I didn't work with json before. Im trying to generate a .json file from the data of my sql database.

```
$con=mysqli_connect(...);
$response = array();
$partik = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM partik");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$nev=$row['im']; 
$leiras=$row['leiras']; 
$kezdes=$row['kezdes'];
$hely=$row['hely'];

$partik[] = array('im'=> $nev, 'leiras'=> $leiras, 'kezdes'=> $kezdes, 'hely'=> $hely);
} 
$response['partik'] = $partik;

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```

The sql connection works.
What is wrong in my code? I get a .json file, but with null value.

Comment: So `var_dump($response);` is null?

Comment: what debugging have you tried? what does `print_r($response)` look like? are you certain the program goes into the loop? etc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Actually it's working now, i added var_dump(), it gave me the correct result, then i checked the .json file, and it gave correct result as well. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: First of all - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php, then `var_dump($response);` and search for culprit.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your while

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

like that you will get an associatif array